# Python return args passed to another function in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I would like to return something from one function and pass it into another function an example would be

```
def cur_weather():
  cloud = #this value is scraped from website
  temp = #this value is scraped from website
  return temp, cloud

@app.route('/')
def index(temp, cloud):
  temp = temp
  cloud = cloud
  return render_template('index.html', temp=temp, cloud=cloud)
```

i keep getting the error TypeError: index() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

im not sure what im doing wrong or how to pass the returned values from one function into another function

all help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of `temp = temp` and `cloud = cloud`? Also, could you provide the whole traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with passing the results of one function to another, but rather a mismatch in your route decoration and the declaration of your `index` function.

By writing

```
@app.route('/')
def index(temp, cloud):
    ...
```

the parameters `temp` and `cloud` have to come from somewhere. You would need them as path parameters in your route. But I don't think you want them there. I believe what you want is

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    temp, cloud = cur_weather()
    return render_template('index.html', temp=temp, cloud=cloud)
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but it gives me an error saying ValueError: too many values to unpack i just threw example data in there its actually data being scrapped from a website via bs4

Comment: 43 which says   temp, cloud = cur_weather()

Comment: Does cur_weather always do `return temp, cloud` where `temp` and `cloud` are numbers or other simple things?

Comment: No temp is actually a whole bunch of html and cloud is an image

Comment: I'm a little puzzled. As long as you say `return temp, cloud` you should be able to assign the result of calling that function to two variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help i just decided to move the content of the function into the index() instead of having the cur_weather function  and it works perfect like that,  had i had more than just this though i feel it would be easier to manage if everything was in separate functions

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why are you doing it like this.
Just call `cur_weather()` in `index()`.

```
temp, cloud = cur_weather()
```

I think this would be better.